# A question regarding comparison of two terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is a question I have been thinking about for a while but I haven't gotten an answer to it. I think it falls under mathematical logic. Suppose you have two terms a and b and you are trying to find out which one is bigger than the other. I will use the symbol <=> as a comparison symbol. Please note that a,b,x and y are all positive integers.  
a<=>b 
Let us say you square both sides 
$a^2 <=> b^2$ 
Then you multiply both sides by y 
$a^2y <=> b^2y$ 
Finally you divide both sides by x 
$\frac{a^2y}{x} <=> \frac{b^2y}{x}$ 
Then suppose you realize that $\frac{a^2y}{x}=a$. Which means that:

$a<=> \frac{b^2y}{x}$

So note that we still don't know which one is bigger between a and $\frac{b^2y}{x}$. However, my question is this, since $\frac{a^2y}{x}=a$, does it also mean that $\frac{b^2y}{x}=b$? If so, is there any mathematical proof for it? Thank you.

Comment: It is not about logic, but about elementary algebra... When you apply arithmetic/algebraic operations, you have to be careful: $-3 < -2$ but $(-3)^2 > (-2)^2$. Different for $=$: if $a=b$ then a+something=b+something, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for that observation. Indeed it is true that negative integers behave very differently compared positive integers when they are squared. However, Every term in my question is a positive integer. I had forgotten to include that fact but now I have included it in the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<=>` symbol is being misleadingly/confusingly suggestive. Essentially, you are asking whether $\dfrac{a^2y}{x}=a$ implies that $\dfrac{b^2y}{x}=b.$

Try using $(a,b,x,y)=(7,3,7,1)$ in your algorithm to see that the answer to your question is No.